# Java file reading & string splitting problems

Tags: java, file

My problem is the next:
1. I should get back 40 lines, but i get only 20.
2. The biggest problem is that i get back NULL for all lines. Why is that? What is the problem with the file reading?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Program{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String[] egysor = new String[5];
        String line;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("szavazatok.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int n=0;
    Sor[] sorok = new Sor[100];

    while(br.readLine()!=null){
        sorok[n] = new Sor();
        egysor = br.readLine().split(" ");

        sorok[n].setKorzet(egysor[0]);
        sorok[n].setSzavazat(Integer.parseInt(egysor[1]));
        sorok[n].setVezNev(egysor[2]);
        sorok[n].setUtoNev(egysor[3]);
        sorok[n].setPart(egysor[4]);
        n++;
        System.out.println(sorok[n]);
    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

and my class:

```
public class Sor {
private String korzet, vezNev, utoNev, part;
private int szavazat;`

public String getKorzet() {
    return korzet;
}

public void setKorzet(String korzet) {
    this.korzet = korzet;
}

public String getVezNev() {
    return vezNev;
}

public void setVezNev(String vezNev) {
    this.vezNev = vezNev;
}

public String getUtoNev() {
    return utoNev;
}

public void setUtoNev(String utoNev) {
    this.utoNev = utoNev;
}

public String getPart() {
    return part;
}

public void setPart(String part) {
    this.part = part;
}

public int getSzavazat() {
    return szavazat;
}

public void setSzavazat(int szavazat) {
    this.szavazat = szavazat;
}


public Sor(){
    this.korzet = korzet;
    this.vezNev = vezNev;
    this.utoNev = utoNev;
    this.part = part;
    this.szavazat = szavazat;
}

public String toString(){
    return "korzet"+korzet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop is eating up half the lines.

```
while(br.readLine()!=null)
```

the loop test condition will read a line. And you basically throw this data away.
Then in the loop you read the next line and actually process it.
What you need to do is this.

```
String inputLine = br.readLine();
while (inputLine != null){
     //...your logic.
     inputLine=br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `BufferedReader.readline()` will consume and return the line that was just read.

[BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a >line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed >immediately by a linefeed.
>
> **Returns**:
>   A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line->termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Try this:

```
String line;

while( (line = br.readLine() ) != null) {
    sorok[n] = new Sor();
    egysor = line.split(" ");

    sorok[n].setKorzet(egysor[0]);
    sorok[n].setSzavazat(Integer.parseInt(egysor[1]));
    sorok[n].setVezNev(egysor[2]);
    sorok[n].setUtoNev(egysor[3]);
    sorok[n].setPart(egysor[4]);
    n++;
    System.out.println(sorok[n]);
}
```

Comment: thanks now i get back 40, but all the lines are NULL :( WHY?